# Why is app link and verification not working on android

Tags: android, adb, deep-linking, android-app-links

Cannot verify app link for my app on android devices. Using `example.com` for domain, and `com.example.app` for app id instead of the **real** one.

1. I can launch app by `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://example.com/ com.example.app`
2. launching with `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://example.com/`, with just url, doesn't work and chrome opens with the link.
3. `App Info > Open by Default > Verified links` for this `com.example.app` is empty and greyed out.
4. `adb shell pm get-app-links com.example.app` returns/prints nothing
5. Could not find any logs with `adb logcat -e "(IntentFilterIntentOp|IntentFilterIntentSvc)"` when installing this app, opening it, keeping it open for more than 20 secs, or re-verifying the app-link with `adb shell pm verify-app-links -- re-verify`
6. `curl https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json -I` returns the following output:

```bash
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Jun 2023 09:05:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 337
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Jun 2023 08:40:55 GMT
ETag: "151-5fd0d65109bf8"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Sat, 01 Jul 2023 09:05:51 GMT
Vary: User-Agent
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: https: *.googleadservices.com *.doubleclick.net *.google.com *.googletagmanager.com *.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com *.facebook.net; frame-ancestors 'self'
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Feature-Policy: microphone 'none'; geolocation 'none'
Expect-CT: max-age=0
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=wkXkFwgBEGc6Ghwu.9PHLwFccvVaqOaV0zj8WyBdDf0-1685610351-0-AeqBrPqaw4CpOpFKrWxzWbN7139MTi3/194uecclD0smsP++N2TXfshkdaoVy4FtqyWm1JfEkkKH3joUoPoU2HY=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jun-23 09:35:51 GMT; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 7d064c15bf09f44a-BOM
```

where the content of this assetlinks.json is below and the SHA256 signature matches with the signature of the key I use for building the release apk.

```json
[
    {
        "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "android_app",
            "package_name": "com.example.com",
            "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["SO:ME:FA:KE:SH:A2:56:5C:57:D7:22:D4:ED:A3:C4:97:23:A2:4E:B0:30:93:A5:57:39:98:B1:E0:3E:03:64:73"]
        }
    }
]
```

7. Running  `curl "https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"` returns the following json:

```bash
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "source": {
        "web": {
          "site": "https://example.com."
        }
      },
      "relation": "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls",
      "target": {
        "androidApp": {
          "packageName": "com.example.app",
          "certificate": {
            "sha256Fingerprint": "SO:ME:FA:KE:SH:A2:56:5C:57:D7:22:D4:ED:A3:C4:97:23:A2:4E:B0:30:93:A5:57:39:98:B1:E0:3E:03:64:73"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "maxAge": "589172.377669267s"
}
```

8. I get the below output only when I run `adb shell pm get-app-links --user cur com.example.app`

```bash
    User 0:
      Verification link handling allowed: true
      Selection state:
        Disabled:
          example.com
```

9. I've also added a custom url scheme to the app manifest which works fine.

I am testing the app link on Android 13, Oneplus Nord 2, and an Android 12 device. I could not find any documentation where there was a discussion of a case with no output upon running `adb shell pm get-app-links com.example.app`.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Common mistakes that I encountered while implementing deeplinks for Android App. Please verify these in your Android code:

1. Make sure that the Activity which is receiving the deeplink intent should be `android:exported="true"`
2. Make sure your intent filter is defined properly `

   ```
       <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

           <data android:scheme="https" />
           <data android:host="example.com" />
           <data android:pathPrefix="/xyz/verify" />
       </intent-filter>`
   ```
3. The SHA-256 keys are different for builds made from internal-app sharing, locally build , and play console signed build for release so suggesting to also verify the build apk SHA-256 key with an app called [Asset Links Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.conn.assetlinkstool&hl=en&gl=US)
4. Also make sure that your assetLinks.json page is accessible publicly take the example for [google](https://www.google.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json)

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the same issue. Suddenly our deep linking not worked. When we analyze our we came to know that our deep link scheme is referenced from strings.xml. Even though we set translatable=false the strings are mentioned in other languages strings.xml. Because of these issue we hardcoded our scheme, path didnt referred from strings.xml. Hope this answer may be useful